# Приложение работает в Debug, странно работает в Release и не работает при билде

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, мобильная-разработка, xamarin.forms

Если я запускаю приложение с конфигурацией Debug, то всё в порядке. При запуске же в Release оно запускается на устройстве, но при этом значок запуска не заменяется кнопками стоп и пауза, как это происходит в Debug ([image: введите сюда описание изображения]).А остаётся таким же, как будто я и не запускал приложение[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настройках я убрал галочку с "Оптимизировать код" и все проблемы решились.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать перейти на API только ниже версией, мне так помогло